# TryGetValue in C# doesn't work on strings, does it?

Tags: c#, casting

*The object `Row` is a class, that has a property `Values` which is a Dictionary.*

Below are extension methods on the Values property.

```
public static T TryGetValue<T>(this Row row, string key)
{
return TryGetValue(row, key, default(T));
}

public static T TryGetValue<T>(this Row row, string key, T defaultValue)
{
    object objValue;

    if (row.Values.TryGetValue(key, out objValue))
    {
        return (T)objValue;
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
```

If I do:

```
user.Username = user.Values.TryGetValue<string>("Username");
```

This happends if the key "username" is not in the Dictionary.

I get an exception, invalid cast:

The following error ocurred:

System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

```
TryGetValue[T](Row row, String key, T defaultValue) 

TryGetValue[T](Row row, String key)
```

**So I guess `TryGetValue` doesn't work on strings?**

Comment: you could probably use T objValue = default(T); since your using a generic signature.

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible you've got an entry in your dictionary with key "Username" whose value is **not a string**?

I've added comments to your method explaining how this could lead to your issue.

```
// I'm going to go ahead and assume your Values property
// is a Dictionary<string, object>
public static T TryGetValue<T>(this Row row, string key, T defaultValue)
{
    // objValue is declared as object, which is fine
    object objValue;

    // this is legal, since Values is a Dictionary<string, object>;
    // however, if TryGetValue returns true, it does not follow
    // that the value retrieved is necessarily of type T (string) --
    // it could be any object, including null
    if (row.Values.TryGetValue(key, out objValue))
    {
        // e.g., suppose row.Values contains the following key/value pair:
        // "Username", 10
        //
        // then what you are attempting here is (string)int,
        // which throws an InvalidCastException
        return (T)objValue;
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should work fine, either if the key "Username" is in the dictionary with a corresponding string value, or not in the dictionary at all.

The fact that you're getting an `InvalidCastException` shows that the value for the `"Username"` key wasn't a string.

Comment: there is another overload I didn't put in sorry.

Comment: @Blankman: I suggest you edit your post to clarify: 1) The overload; 2) What exactly Row is - you say it's an *object* of type `Dictionary<string, object>` but it's clearly a *type* rather than an object; 3) the exception you're getting.

Comment: ok after tracing my code, it seems if the key is not present in the dictionary, it throws an exception (invalid cast).

Comment: @Blankman: It shouldn't do that - it should return the default value. But then again, you're calling a method you haven't shown us, so it's hard to tell...

Comment: @Blankman: I don't believe it's really happening if Username isn't in the dictionary - it will happen if the key is in the dictionary, but with a non-string value. If you are absolutely sure it's not in the dictionary, please post a short but complete program demonstrating it...